# Redirected to compute.amazonaws.com

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm running nginx on a basic AWS EC2 instance.

My nginx http server block looks like this:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80;

    # TLS redirect
    server_name ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

My https server block works fine, so when I enter:

```
https://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com
```

In my browser, everything works, but when I enter:

```
http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com (http, not https)
```

I get redirected to

```
https://compute.amazonaws.com
```

Is there any obvious reason for this? Thanks in advance.

**Edit with curl**

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ curl -v http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com
* Rebuilt URL to: http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com/
*   Trying 172.31.14.246...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com (xxx.xx.xx.xxx) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.10.2
< Date: Mon, 24 Apr 2017 22:09:39 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 185
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com
< 
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.2</center>
</body>
</html>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com left intact
```

Comment: Using `$server_name` instead of `$host` may mitigate the problem.

Comment: This yields the same result. I made sure to restart nginx after changing this.

Comment: `https://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com` isn't a target for which you should have been able to obtain an SSL certificate.  How did you manage to do that?  Have you tried `curl -v http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com`?  Could it be that the browser is engaging in some beneficent skulduggery based on an HSTS or pinning policy from compute.amazonaws.com or something related to the public suffix list?  Show the response headers that `curl` generates. (Edit into the question, please.)

Comment: I made a certificate without going through a CA. Eventually, I will get a proper certificate for the real domain. Do you think this is the root cause of the problem? curl was the next thing I tried. It seems to work.